# Selecting a variable to use at php mailer

Tags: php

I'm using a simple php mailer for my sites contact form. I have a form asking first for their subject of contact, and if they select a spesific option, then the recipient selection will fade in and you can select the recipient you want to use. BUT. I don't want to write the email addresses in the code, because of spam. So I'm trying to achieve this via php variables.

My mailer looks like this:

```
<?php
$var1="xxx@gmail.com";
$var2="xxx@gmail.com";
$to = "$_POST[kohde]";
$subject = "$_POST[asia]";
$message = "
$_POST[tiedot]\n
$_POST[nimi]
$_POST[email]
$_POST[puhelin]
IP-osoite: $_POST[ip] ";
$from = "xxx.fi";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

But using the variable names as is in value wont work. So how would I select the email to use with the option without hard coding the email to the option value?

```
 <select name="kohde" style="width:233px;" >
    <option value="$var1">xxx.fi</option>
    <option value="$var">Sivun tekijälle</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: you should use <?=$var1;?> to print a variable. This however doesn't solver your problem. You could set option value='1' and in php set the email `if($_POST['kohde']=='1')$to='xxx@gmail.com';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way...

Use this PHP to get the $to address:

```
$goodAddresses = array(1 => 'a@x.com', 2 => 'b@x.com');
$to = 'default@x.com';
if(isset($goodAddresses[$_POST['kohde']])) {
    $to = $goodAddresses[$_POST['kohde']];
}
```

And change the values of your select options in our html file to match the array keys in the PHP:

```
<select name="kohde" style="width:233px;" >
    <option value="1">xxx.fi</option>
    <option value="2">Sivun tekijälle</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it easier to understand. the first part goes in your PHP code to set the $to variable. The second part is a small change to your html.

Comment: I'm using Dreamweaver and it's giving me syntax errors... I really suck at php, and have no idea what is wrong with it? It gives the syntax errors from the 
if(isset($goodAddresses[$_POST['kohde']) {
and the
$to = $goodAddresses[$_POST['kohde']; parts
So what do I need to do?

Comment: Sorry. I left out a closing square bracket on those lines. There should be two in a row: `]]`  I've edited the answer to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to write some really basic functions, but if I get a function to use, and it has one mistake, I can't get it working.

Comment: It still produces a syntax error. I just hardcoded it to the code.

Comment: I missed another bracket. I've added it to the answer: `]]))`  Sorry about my clumsy syntax. I haven't tested the code and I've got a lot of code of my own to concentrate on. :)

Comment: As a general troubleshooting rule, that's a good thing to check: make sure all open parenthesis and brackets have a matching closing bracket. And make sure all lines have a semicolon ending. That'll take care of probably a third of all bugs you'll find.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code should be this:

```
<?php
$var1="xxx@gmail.com";
$var2="xxx@gmail.com";

$to = $_POST["kohde"];
$subject = $_POST["asia"];

$message = $_POST["tiedot"] . 
$_POST["nimi"] . 
$_POST["email"] . 
$_POST["puhelin"] . 
"IP-osoite:" . $_POST["ip"];

$from = $_POST["kohde"];
$headers = "From:" . $from;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

You have to put the quotes around the array selectors, within the brackets, not around the whole variable name. Also, you can add the form value as `$from` using `$_POST["kohde"]`.